# Event Listener for input button

Tags: jquery, input, event-listener

Hello I'm trying to add an event listener to an input button using js but it doesn't work.

Here's my html code:

```
<div class="cc-controls u-clearfix">
  <input class="primary confirm js-add-card" type="submit" value="Add">
  <a class="icon-lg icon-close dark-hover js-cancel" href="#"></a>
  <a class="cc-opt icon-lg icon-dropdown-menu dark-hover js-cc-menu" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

My js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-add-card').click(function() {
      alert('hello');
  }); 
});
```

Comment: what the mean of doesn't work.?? any errors?? jquery included??

Comment: see here: https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/kd9s6L3y/

Comment: it doesn't get fired. And, when I inspect the page, this event listener isn't placed in the list of click event listeners .

Comment: Are there any errors in the debug console?  Is jQuery included in your page before your JS code?  There's nothing wrong with your code as shown so it's probably an error in your page causing this code either not to execute or not to have access to jQuery.  Also, if this `<input>` control is in a form, you will also have to stop any form submission.

Comment: @eugensunic Yes, it works on fiddle but not on my browser.

Comment: put this in  the <head> section: <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

Comment: @jfriend00 I only have this JS code. And, what console.log() shows looks just fine.

Comment: did you put the code that I told you into your head section?

Comment: @eugensunic I'm using jquery 2.1.4 version. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Replace it then with lower version, but you should be using the on function. Nevermind put the lower version and then report.

Comment: @eugensunic Even though I did what you told me, it still doesn't get fired

Comment: Can you put your example on the fiddle? but entier html code...

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I tried 'input[value=Add]' instead of '.js-add-card'. It worked. Thanks A LOT!!!

Comment: @eugensunic I really need an option to downvote some of your comments    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>  will not work with anyone who didn't downloaded the same js file in the index path with the same file name ... 2nd there is no difference to advice him to downgrade juqery version

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef, well then, go on meta, and ask them what you want...

Comment: @PhillipHG - If switching to `input[value=Add]` somehow magically works now, then your question is NOT showing something about your situation because your original code in your question works just fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/11zhntqp/.  There is obviously something else wrong.  Probably, you don't have the actual class name you think you do or you have an error in your page.

Comment: @eugensunic - there is NO reason to switch to `.on()` here.  `.click()` works just fine.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/11zhntqp/.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[class*=js-add-card]').click(function() {
      alert('hello');
  }); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rjLrmhL2/

Comment: I can't see any difference between this code and OP code

Comment: OP code is targeting the element using class(.) selector and the code above is targeting using contains selector.

Comment: Your code gave me some hints. I tried input[value=Add] which is a bit different than your code. It worked. Thanks

Comment: Hmmm this is really strange,, it should have worked with what you posted anyways

Comment: @PhillipHG: 'value' attribute could be misleading. Thats why classes are always the best choice.

Comment: If everything is as the OP said, there is NO reason that this code should work and the OP's code would not work as one can clearly see from this: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/11zhntqp/.  So, I find no explanation for how this is actually an answer to the question asked.

Comment: It just started not working after I refreshed the page... @jfriend00 yes, you're right. My JS code should just work fine. There should be a problem with the page.

Comment: I'm not good at debugging using console.log(). When I console.log($('.js-add-card')) I get 0 for the length.

Comment: @PhillipHG - A zero length that means that jQuery did not find the element you are trying to target.  That means either that you are running this code too early (before that element is loaded) or you are not targeting the right selector to find that element.  By any chance is this HTML dynamically loaded in a frame or loaded via Javascript?  If you want to continue to work on this problem and perhaps solicit other answers, you should uncheck the green checkmark.  That indicates you're done with this problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 I thought I unchecked the green mark. This HTML is provided by Trello.com, not my code.

Comment: @PhillipHG - as you can see, the JS in your code works just fine in a JSFiddle made from your code.  So, there's obviously something else going on in your real page.  If you want more help from us, you will have to figure out how to share more info about your real page with us.  Can you share an actual link to the page that doesn't work reliably?